# Why can I not get the Year from a NSString using NSDateFormatter dateFromString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

if ([dateFormatter dateFromString:@"11/09/2010"])
{
   //PASS
}
else
{
   //FAIL
}
```

Why is it going into the FAIL section every time?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the date format like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

Or the other way around, depending on which field is days and which is months.

Comment: may need to be dd/MM/yyyy (or the other way around)

Comment: @AndrewCarter yep, you are right, thanks. I changed my answer so it is correct.

Comment: To explain: @EthanAllen, you've told the date formatter to expect a 4-digit year *and nothing else*. Since what you're feeding it doesn't match what you've told it to expect, it fails.